# How do I call a function on selected element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Warning: stupid question!
But I have tried looking this up and I can't figure out what to search for or what I am doing wrong.
I am trying to make an image fade in, here is my code:

```
$('.Middle-Tennessee').show().showNice(this);
```

and later I have my function:

```
function showNice(x){
    x.css('opacity', '0');
    x.animate({
        opacity: 1,
    }, 5000);
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What does (or should) `this` refer to in your example?

Comment: I thought it would refer to $('.Middle-Tennessee')

Comment: what about `$('.Middle-Tennessee').show(5000)`?

Comment: It certainly does not refer to `$('.Middle-Tennessee')`. Learn more about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: `$('.Middle-Tennessee').hide().fadeIn(5000);`

Comment: @AvL That's pretty fat, but I don't really want the image to change sizes, is there a way to evoke that action without the image changing size?

Comment: @watson: Have a look at all the jQuery effects methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/.

Comment: @wason: Look at @Boaz Answer: `$('.Middle-Tennessee').fadeIn(5000)` that's what I wanted to write...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a bunch of different options here depending mostly upon how you want to write your code:

You use `.each()` to iterate over a jQuery function and call your own function on each item in the collection:

```
$('.Middle-Tennessee').show().each(function(index, element) {
    showNice($(element));
});
```

---

Or, because your `showNice()` function expects a jQuery collection already, you could also do this:

```
var items = $('.Middle-Tennessee').show();
showNice(items);
```

---

Or, you could ditch the `showNice()` function and just use jQuery chaining:

```
$('.Middle-Tennessee').show().css("opacity", 0).animate({opacity: 1}, 5000);
```

---

Or you could use built-in jQuery animations instead of the show, opacity and animate:

```
$('.Middle-Tennessee').fadeIn(5000);
```

---

Or, you could make `showNice()` be a jquery plugin like this:

```
jQuery.fn.showNice = function() {
    this.css('opacity', '0').animate({
        opacity: 1,
    }, 5000);
    return this;
}
```

And, then you can use showNice just like a jQuery method:

```
$('.Middle-Tennessee').show().showNice();
```

Comment: Thanks. However, that's overly complicated since `css` and `animate` use `each` internally already. +1 for second solution.

Comment: @Bergi - I added several more options.

Answer (score 4):

```
showNice($('.Middle-Tennessee').show());


function showNice(x){
    x.css('opacity', '0');
    x.animate({
        opacity: 1,
    }, 5000);
}
```

OR

YOu can use jquery fadein

```
$('.Middle-Tennessee').hide().fadeIn(5000);
```

Comment: Because the function showNice essentially becomes `$('.Middle-Tennessee').show().css('opacity, '0'); $('.Middle-Tennessee').show().animate({{opacity: 1,}, 5000);`

Comment: Dude $('.Middle-Tennessee').show() will return $('.Middle-Tennessee') 'jQuery element. I believe you know how jquery chaining work. showNice($('.Middle-Tennessee').show()) is equal to $('.Middle-Tennessee').show() and showNice($('.Middle-Tennessee'));

Comment: My mistake. Sorry about that.

Comment: This should be the most voted answer. It was the first one to show how to use the existing `showNice` function, and to point out it's unnecessary and replaceable by `fadeIn`.

Answer (score 4):

`showNice` is not a jQuery method, it expects the jQuery collection as its argument:

```
showNice($('.Middle-Tennessee').show());
```

To make it work with `$('.Middle-Tennessee').show().showNice();`, you'd need to add it to the jQuery collection prototype (via the shortcut `$.fn`):

```
$.fn.showNice = function showNice() {
    this.css('opacity', '0');
    this.animate({
        opacity: 1,
    }, 5000);
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply pass the jQuery object to your function as a *parameter*:

```
showNice($('.Middle-Tennessee'));
```

-- OR --

You can also use jQuery's [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) *method*:

```
$('.Middle-Tennessee').fadeIn(5000);
```

Note the difference between the usage of your Javascript *function* in the first example and the native jQuery *method* in the second.